# Linear maps and subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, linear-transformations

The set-up for my question is this, let $k \le n$, let $E \subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$ be a $k$-dimensional subspace. Let $I \subseteq \{1,\ldots, n\}$ such that $|I| = k$, then we can define coordinate subspaces, $\mathbf{R}^I$ and $\mathbf{R}^J$, where 
$$\mathbf{R}^I = \{(x^1, \ldots, x^n) : \forall  i \in I, x^i = 0\}$$

and such that $J = \{1,\ldots, n\} \setminus I$. Suppose we have picked a subset $I$ such that $E \cap \mathbf{R}^J = \{0\}$ (where $\mathbf{R}^J$ is the orthogonal complement of $\mathbf{R}^I$), then we can view $E$ as the graph of a unique linear map $A_I$, that is, $E = \{x + A_I(x) : x \in \mathbf{R}^I\}$, where

$$A_I : \mathbf{R}^I \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^J$$

Now, I'm wondering, is there are nice way of representing $A_I$ as an $n\times n$-matrix?

I know such a linear map should exist and at first glance it appears as though if one wanted to represent it as an $n\times n$-matrix then the rows of the matrix which are indexed by $I$ should be all zeroes (or something to this extent), so to ensure that for $v \in \mathbf{R}^I$ we have $A_Iv \in \mathbf{R}^J$, but it seems like there should be more characterizing features (like $A_I$ should be symmetric maybe?), I really am not sure. Are any of my thoughts right and are there more things that can be said about the form of this matrix(/linear map)? Any help would de much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what the role of $E$ is here. (If it is a graph, why does it have the same dimension as $R^j$? Maybe I'm misunderstanding.) But otherwise I think your first intuition is right. Symmetric $A$ will work, but it probably isn't necessary. Consider a simple example, $n = 4$, $I = \{1,2\}$, $J = \{3,4\}$. Then definitely $A_{3:4,1:2} = 0$ but what happens in $A_{1:2,3:4}$ won't matter.

Comment: The subspace $E$ comes from a slightly bigger context, specifically, $E \in GR(k,n)$, where $Gr(k,n)$ denotes the real Grassmannian (subspaces of dimension $k$ in $\mathbf{R}^n$). But anyway my question is then more or less, given some subspace $E$ is there a nice way to find/describe the map $A_I$ (where $A_I$ is the "graph" described above)? loosely speaking The reason I care about the transformation $A_I$ is because one can define charts on $Gr(k,n)$ by sending $E \mapsto A_I$. I just don't know how to talk about properties of $Gr(k,n)$ without some explicit formulation of the $A_I$.

Comment: Oh ok I think I'm starting to understand what the question is :) So I'm still a little caught up on dimensions. $E$ is a set of length $n$ vectors but has dimension $k$, so it can be represented as a range of some $n\times k$ matrix? But you want a matrix $A$ that can map vectors of length $k$ into $E$? Is it something like that? The $x+A(x)$ thing is throwing me off because it doesn't seem like those vectors would have the same length and neither is length $n$. (Sorry I'm unfamiliar with Grassmannians so maybe that's where my confusion is.)

Comment: Yes, $E$ can definitely be represented as the range of some $n times k$-matrix but thats not quite what I want. the $x + A_I(x)$ thing really is just a formalism, notice that $x \in \mathbf{R}^I \subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$ and $A_I(x) \in \mathbf{R}^J$, where we can decompose $\mathbf{R}^n$ as the direct sum $\mathbf{R}^I \oplus \mathbf{R}^J$. Now if you're given some $y \in E$, we can write $y$ _uniquely_ as the sum of two vectors $y = x + z$, such that $x \in \mathbf{R}^I$, $z \in \mathbf{R}^J$, (Thus $A_I(x) = z$).

Comment: So essentially, given a vector $y \in E$ one can project it onto the coordinate subspaces in a unique way $y = x + z$, and so in turn we can define a linear map ($A_I: \mathbf{R}^I \subseteq \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^J \subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$) taking one of the projected elements ($x$) to the other ($z = A_I(x)$), and this is the map I want to know about.

Comment: Ah ok, but still I like to think of $E$ as the range space of a $n\times k$ matrix (let's call it $B$.) Then using the partition $B = \left[\begin{matrix}B_1 \\ B_2\end{matrix}\right]$ where $B_1$ is a $k\times k$ nonsingular matrix, then $E = \{Bu \mid u\in \mathbb R^k\}$ and $Bu = \left[\begin{matrix} B_1 \\ B_2 \end{matrix}\right]u = \left[\begin{matrix}x \\ B_2B_1^{-1}x\end{matrix}\right]$, where $x = B_1^{-1}u$, which I think gives you what you want? (Basically $A_I = B_2B_1^{-1}$.) Will that work?

Comment: That's an interesting take. I think you're right, it does look like $B_2B_1^{-1}$ is essentially the desired matrix (modulo some appropriately places zeroes to turn it into an $n \times n$-matrix).